# Run schedule every five minutes (like 00:05, 00:10...) in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, scheduled-tasks

I want to run the schedule every five minutes. 
like `12:00`, `12:05`, `12:10`...`n`

I'm using the Schedule Frequency Options :
`->everyFiveMinutes();`

But sometime it will start `12:02`, `12:07`, `12:12`...`n` It's wrong for me.

So how can I run schedule every five mins special mins like +5?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $schedule->command('your:job')->cron('5 0 * * *');
```

The command in this like will be executed at the five minutes of every day (0h05 or 12h05am) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to express this in cron notation:

```
$schedule->command('my:command')->cron('0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *');
```